# Same SQLite database content but different size on disk

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a **SQLite 3** database, which is populated by a Windows application running on a Windows Server.
This application caches data coming from one of two functionally identical Servers:
- one running on Linux, and storing its data in a DB2 database
- one running on Windows, and storing its data in a MSSQL database.

The SQLite database contains just one table created by the application to cache the data, that is created by the statement:

```
CREATE TABLE RESULTS ( sysID_runID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

The data cached in this table in the two cases (data coming from Linux/DB2 or from Windows/MSSQL) are exactly the same: same number of rows(up to 1 million), same min, avg and max.

However, the database coming from Linux/DB2 is about 4% grater in size on filesystem then the one coming from Windows/MSSQL, and also the time to populate it is greater, more or less of the same extent.

Since I'm dealing with `INTEGER` values I would exclude an Encoding issue, but I don't know what could be the cause of this size/performance difference.

Thanks for any hint you can provide!

Comment: How are the databases being transmitted? Does performing a `VACUUM` resolve the difference?

Comment: Are the differences in the output of [sqlite-analyzer](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) for both files? (I'd guess the page size is different.)

Comment: @Tommy

databases data are transmitted via http from Linux or Windows Server (which in turn query them from their respective DB) to the Windows application that caches them into the SQLite database.
My problem is the performance gap in the two cases, so I would like to understand why I have it and hopefully avoid it at all.

Comment: sqlite-analyzer shows same page size (4096) but:

First value is GOOD CASE (from Windows)
Second is BAD CASE (from Linux)

Bytes of storage consumed..... 26550272 - 27328512 
Bytes of payload.............. 3835500 14.4% - 3835500 14.0%
Average unused bytes per entry 0.02 - 0.42    
Average fanout................ 231.00 - 238.00   
Primary pages used............ 6454 - 6644    
Total pages used.............. 6482 - 6672   
Unused bytes on index pages... 19072 16.6% - 16264 14.2% 
Unused bytes on primary pages. 12061 0.046% - 788781 2.9%
Unused bytes on all pages..... 31133 0.12% - 805045 2.9%